# XML: Same parent

Tags: xml, t-sql

How could I design an XML query to return all children with the same parent under the same Path?
e.g.

```
create table parent_child
(
ParentID varchar(50),
ChildID varchar(50)
)
insert parent_child
values ('Parent1','Child1'),('Parent1','Child2'),('Parent1','Child3'),('Parent4','Child4'),('Parent5','Child5')
select * from parent_child
```

Using this code:

```
Select  
ParentID ,
ChildID

FROM parent_child
FOR XML PATH('Parent'), type, root('Provider')
```

This is displaying as:

```
<Provider>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent1</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child1</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent1</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child2</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent1</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child3</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent4</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child4</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent5</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child5</ChildID>
  </Parent>
</Provider>
```

When instead, I want this to display as:

```
<Provider>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent1</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child1</ChildID>
    <ChildID>Child2</ChildID>
    <ChildID>Child3</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent4</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child4</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent5</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child5</ChildID>
  </Parent>
</Provider>
```

How do I design this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work. I've switched your sample data to a table variable, just to make the script self contained and repeatable without leaving any artifacts behind:

```
declare @parent_child table
(
ParentID varchar(50),
ChildID varchar(50)
)
insert @parent_child
values ('Parent1','Child1'),('Parent1','Child2'),('Parent1','Child3'),
       ('Parent4','Child4'),('Parent5','Child5')
select * from @parent_child

select
    ParentID,
    (select ChildID
     from @parent_child pc2
     where pc2.ParentID = pc1.ParentID for xml path(''),type)
from (select Distinct ParentID from @parent_child) pc1
for xml path('Parent'), type, root('Provider')
```

Result:

```
<Provider>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent1</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child1</ChildID>
    <ChildID>Child2</ChildID>
    <ChildID>Child3</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent4</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child4</ChildID>
  </Parent>
  <Parent>
    <ParentID>Parent5</ParentID>
    <ChildID>Child5</ChildID>
  </Parent>
</Provider>
```

The key part really is generating the `Child` elements in a correlated subquery, ensuring that they're not separately wrapped (`PATH('')`) and that the result is treated as already formed XML (`TYPE`) in the outer query.